# Saving array to file txt

Tags: php, arrays, file, save

i'm having trouble saving the table data to a file correctly.

1. loading data into an array from a file
2. I check if the code entered from the  field is in the table
3. if so, I change this entry in the table
4. I write the table to the txt file in the form
      number1
      number2
      number3

but there is something wrong

my code

```
$find = $_POST['pole_1'];

$array = [];
$array = file('voucher.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

// check array after read from file
print_r($array);

echo '<br />';echo '<br />';

// I check if it is in the array and if so I change the number
for( $i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++ ) {  

    if ($find === $array[$i]) {
        echo "Match found"; echo '<br />';
        $array[$i] = $array[$i] . '_code_use';   
    } else if ($find == ''){
        echo "Empty field"; echo '<br />';

    } else {
        echo "Match NOT found"; echo '<br />';

    }
}

// check array after changge
echo '<br />';
print_r($array);

// Saving to file
$file = 'new.txt';
for( $i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++ ) {  
    $data = $array[$i]."\n";
    file_put_contents($file, $data);

}
```

File Voucher.txt. -> array

```
01238
08752
09765
```

$find = '08752'

Array after loop for, I want this save to file

```
01238
08752_code_use
09765
```

Comment: _"but there is something wrong"_ This is vague and not helpful. Please describe what you expect to happen, what actually happens, what error messages you receive, etc.

Comment: `file_put_contents('new.txt', join(PHP_EOL, $array));` is enough.

Comment: Would it be easier to keep the file as JSON which would make the process easier.

Comment: thx very much, its work!

Comment: For future reference, if you want to append to a text file instead of overwriting it, you need to add that flag: `file_put_contents($file, $content, FILE_APPEND)`

Comment: all in all i just wanted to overwrite the old txt file. Thank you for your help